# 4k Nvidia performance on Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I have an NVidia GTX 960 (edit: also tried a Quadro M4000) on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.1 install. The rendering performance is pretty terrible, see [stuttering video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7soQIFdbWz4)

It looks to me like it has a really hard time context switching. When I have multiple windows open, it takes a second or two to get focus into a new window. I didn't have any of these problems with my previous Iris Pro graphics computer in 4k, so not sure why a several hundred dollar video card can't keep up.

I can't be the only one trying to do this, anyone have it working? I am currerntly on the nvidia-370 graphics drivers, but I've tried everything down to 35X-something.

Relevant Logs:

- [nvidia-smi](http://pastebin.com/raw/MjkxqEyT)
- [glxinfo](http://pastebin.com/raw/p0tanueK)

---

*Additional Info*

Turning off vsync on both compiz and nvidia, as well as completely disabling chrome GPU functions has made it more usable.

If I open up something else that is GPU bound, like a Steam game, the performance goes right to crap again. Really looks like its related to GPU context switching performance being atrocious.

Performance has gotten much better adding these to my /etc/profile:

```
export __GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=0
export __GL_YIELD="USLEEP"
export __GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the related links [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582887/my-nvidia-gtx-960-card-creates-opengl-problems-with-unity-on-ubuntu) reports the card is working with ubuntu one year ago. Are you sure the nvidia driver is picked? Check your Xorg.log

You also could have a look at [this other post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2263316) that details how to enforce correct manual install of nvidia drivers, and reports correct 4k performance with you card.

Anyway, I have a 4k screen running smoothly on GeForce GTX 750 - just answered your question because no-one else seemed to.

Comment: I suspect he has the Nvidia driver selected. I'm seeing the exact same symptoms with Nvidia Quattro @ 4K on the 375 driver.